# $z^2 +z|z|+|2z|^2=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all complex solutions of the equation  $z^2 +z|z|+|2z|^2=0.$

My approach is as follows,

Let $z=rw$ , where $r=|z|$ and $w$ is a unimodular complex number.
The above equation could now be written as $r^2(w^2+w+4)=0$.
If $r=0$ we get $z=0$. Now let $r≠0$. The above equation simplifies to $w^2+w+4=0$.
After solving I got $|w|=2$ thus contadicting the fact that $w$ is unimodular.

Is $z=0$ the only solution or are there more solutions? Please correct me if I made mistakes anywhere.

Comment: YOu are correct

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi Agreed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also write
\begin{equation}
4 |z|^2 = |2z|^2= |z^2+z|z||\le|z^2|+|z||z| = 2 |z|^2
\end{equation}
hence $2|z|^2 \le 0$, hence $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$, $|z|=r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then we get $(x+iy)*2+(xr+iry)+4r^2=0$, separating real and imaginary parts we get $x^2-y^2+rx+4r^2=0$ and $2xy=ry \implies y=0$ or $y=\pm x\sqrt{3}.$

Case 1: $y=0$ gives $x^2-x^2+4x^2=0 \implies x=0$ so $z=0$ is one root.

Case 2: $y=+\sqrt{3}x$ gives $x=0$ so again $z=0$

Case 3: Will again give $z=0$.

So the given equation has just one solution $z=0$.